# What is class correlation?

Tags: correlation, weka

I am referring to `iris.arff` dataset that comes with Weka distribution. There are 3 classes and 4 attributes. It gives below information regarding the 4 attributes-

```
%                  Min  Max   Mean    SD   Class Correlation
%    sepal length: 4.3  7.9   5.84  0.83    0.7826
%     sepal width: 2.0  4.4   3.05  0.43   -0.4194
%    petal length: 1.0  6.9   3.76  1.76    0.9490  (high!)
%     petal width: 0.1  2.5   1.20  0.76    0.9565  (high!)
```

How is the last column computed?

After googling class correlation I found [Intraclass_correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation) Not sure if it's the same thing, also how can a single class correlation number be given when the number of classes is three?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Class Correlation" is Pearson Correlation Coefficient between target variable and the other variables. i.e. corr(Species, sepal length) = 0.7826

Here is the R output (i do not have Weka handy):

```
> iris2 <- data.frame(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Petal.Length, iris$Petal.Width, as.numeric(iris$Species))
> head(iris2)
  iris.Sepal.Length iris.Sepal.Width iris.Petal.Length iris.Petal.Width as.numeric.iris.Species.
1               5.1              3.5               1.4              0.2                        1
2               4.9              3.0               1.4              0.2                        1
3               4.7              3.2               1.3              0.2                        1
4               4.6              3.1               1.5              0.2                        1
5               5.0              3.6               1.4              0.2                        1
6               5.4              3.9               1.7              0.4                        1
> cor(iris2)
                         iris.Sepal.Length iris.Sepal.Width iris.Petal.Length iris.Petal.Width as.numeric.iris.Species.
iris.Sepal.Length                1.0000000       -0.1175698         0.8717538        0.8179411                0.7825612
iris.Sepal.Width                -0.1175698        1.0000000        -0.4284401       -0.3661259               -0.4266576
iris.Petal.Length                0.8717538       -0.4284401         1.0000000        0.9628654                0.9490347
iris.Petal.Width                 0.8179411       -0.3661259         0.9628654        1.0000000                0.9565473
as.numeric.iris.Species.         0.7825612       -0.4266576         0.9490347        0.9565473                1.0000000
```

The last column `as.numeric.iris.Species` is yours `Class Correlation` from Weka. The numbers do not match exactly. This could be cause by:

- different data set size
- different discretisation method (i.e I use setosa = 1, versicolor = 2, and virginica = 3)

Answer (score 2):

Weka is open sourced software, so you can find it out from its source code comment:

"Evaluates the worth of an attribute by measuring the correlation (Pearson's) between it and the class.

Nominal attributes are considered on a value by value basis by treating each value as an indicator. An overall correlation for a nominal attribute is arrived at via a weighted average."

[link](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/attributeSelection/CorrelationAttributeEval.html)

Use 'sepallength' as an example:

1. make a real vector **v1**, each element is petal length, e.g. [5.1, 4.9, 4.7, ..., 5.9]
2. make a real vector **v2**, each element is class indicator, e.g. [1, 1, 1, ...., 1, 2, 2, 2,...2, 3, 3, 3, ... 3]    (there are 50 ones, 50 twos and 50 threes representing three iris class and each class have 50 observations).
3. calculate Pearson correlation between **v1** and **v2**.

For more information, read this Weka source code if you want to re-implement the calculation. [link](https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/trunk/weka/src/main/java/weka/attributeSelection/CorrelationAttributeEval.java).